# How to change color of parent on hover the child element

Tags: html, css

I have a div with social links and I want to make background color to fill whole div when hover any anchor with different color depending on which link is hovered.

For now background changes only beneath the anchor text.

I'm researching the way to fill whole parent with child's background color using pure CSS.

```css
#social {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}
a:hover {
    color: white;
}
#facebook:hover {
    background: #3b5998;
}
#twitter:hover {
    background: lightblue;
}
#google-plus:hover {
    background: tomato;
}
#instagram:hover {
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="social">
               <a id="facebook" href="#"> <span>Facebook</span></a><br>
                <a id="twitter" href="#"> <span>Twitter</span></a><br>
                <a id="google-plus" href="#"> <span>Google plus</span></a><br>
                <a id="instagram" href="#"> <span>Instagram</span></a><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For first sight It looks like another attempt to change style of parent element, but there is a way to achieve the effect using pure CSS.

The way is to use `::after` pseudo-selector for anchor elements. We need to define it as absolutely positioned and set up to 100% dimensions of parent. Also to prevent overlapping of siblings, we need to decrease `z-index` attribute of pseudo-selector to render it beneath text.

Here is a snippet:

```css
#social {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
a::after{
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: transparent;
    transition: background .5s ease;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color .5s ease;
}
a:hover {
    color: white;
}
#facebook:hover::after {
    background: #3b5998;
}
#twitter:hover::after {
    background: lightblue;
}
#google-plus:hover::after {
    background: tomato;
}
#instagram:hover::after {
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="social">
               <a id="facebook" href="#"> <span>Facebook</span></a><br>
                <a id="twitter" href="#"> <span>Twitter</span></a><br>
                <a id="google-plus" href="#"> <span>Google plus</span></a><br>
                <a id="instagram" href="#"> <span>Instagram</span></a><br>
</div>
```

Comment: This is even nicer than [your previous solution](http://www.codeply.com/go/gvLumhaKhT) since it uses `::after` instead of another `div`.

Comment: @JuanMendes Thank you for your advice. I even didn't know about the Q&A mode on SO.