# Highlight span between footer background and content

Tags: javascript, css, z-index, background-color

How can I get this JavaScript highlight span to appear **between** the footer background and the elements that are in the footer?

Increasing the `z-index` of the elements does not seem to accomplish this.

Example one - the highlight appears behind the footer with a partially transparent background.

https://codepen.io/jklemon17/pen/KoydPy

```
.footer {
  background-color: rgba(70, 70, 70, .5);
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom:100px;
/*   z-index: -2; */
}
```

Example two - the highlight appears on top of the footer elements.

https://codepen.io/jklemon17/pen/xWPGBm

```
.footer {
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom:100px;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: insert the span inside the footer instead of the body

Comment: maybe you'd like the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42232998/4206079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the best would be `append` the highlighting element to the footer instead the body, that way the `z-index` would be easier to handle. Change to this on your code:

```
const footer =
document.querySelector('.footer');

highlight.classList.add('highlight');
footer.append(highlight);
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wmPKEy